# Increase in query time in solr 8

Tags: solr, lucene, solr8

While upgrading the solr from version 6.5 to 8.7, we observe the query time has been increased by 40%.

On solr 8.7 the difference between optimized and unoptimized index is also
very huge. 350 ms on optimized and 650 ms on unoptimized. The difference is
only 5 GB in size in cores of optimized and unoptimized. The segment count
in the optimized index is 1 and 20 in the unoptimized index.

I wanted to ask, Is this normal behavior on solr 8.7, or was there some
setting that we forgot to add? Pleas also tell us how can we reduce the
response time in unoptimzed core.

*Specifications*
We are using master slave architecture, Polling interval is 3 hours
RAM- 96 GB
CPU-14
Heap-30 GB
Index Size-95 GB
Segments size-20

**Merge Policy :**
mergePolicyFactory : org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory
maxMergeAtOnce : 5
segmentsPerTier : 3

Answer (score 1):

In Solr 8 [the maxSegmentSizeMB is honored](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7976). If your index is way larger than 5GB, this means in Solr 6 the number of segments is few, but more in Solr 8 because of the size limitation per segment.

The more opened segments in runtime mean a request will look up more segments. Furthermore, the memory allocation will be higher too, and cause GC issues.